# Read-only structure? How can I use the pointer in a struct?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am going crazy with this problem.

I have this self-defined struct

```
struct oneRectangle
{
    QString partName;
    QGraphicsRectItem * rectangle;
};
```

And I have a List use this struct as a template:

```
QList<oneRectangle> partList;
```

After I append an entity of struct(without init the pointer), I need to do something like this:

```
partList.at(index).rectangle = some pointer points to a QGraphicsRectItem
```

But, I got an error saying the struct is a read-only struct. I tried to malloc the pointer first, then append it to the list, But when I assign address to the pointer, I still get the error.
What's the problem here?

Comment: You're using `malloc` and raw pointers in C++? Maybe you should retag your question as `C` instead...

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QList.html#details

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

```
partList.at(index).rectangle
```

into

```
partList[index].rectangle
```

as [`QList::operator[](int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d) returns a modifiable reference, where [`QList::at(int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlist.html#at) returns a const reference (and is thus not modifiable).

Comment: But, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/at/, `std::vector::at` may also return a modifiable reference. Why it returns a const one, in this case?

Comment: `QList::at` behaves differently than `std::vector::at`. See the documentation of QVector (linked in my answer).

Comment: @akappa: Because `std::vector::at` is not `QVector::at`

Comment: ooops. Overlooked that it's a `QList`. **sigh**

Comment: Oh, I wrote about QVector instead of QList, but they behave the same in this case. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is: use something.at(index) for showing and something[index] for editing. Why not use something[] for both? Because i have read it somewhere that ".at()" is more efficient and faster. I did not test it though...